account-index spl-token-mint blows up memory consumption
Trying to run a 1.17.25 RPC node on a 1TB RAM server, enabling various indices one by one:
--account-index program-id brought up used RAM consumption to ~200GB total
--account-index spl-token-owner - to ~300GB total
but..
--account-index spl-token-mint took it over 1.2TB at which point it crashed.
Is this expected and one needs to set up swap space accordingly or not really?

Although I'm surprised that your machine isn't handling all the indexes with that much RAM, it's generally expected unfortunately. Swap space will likely slow down the node and make it unable to keep up with the network.
You can read more about the requirements for an RPC node at https://docs.solanalabs.com/operations/requirements#rpc-node-recommendations
